# Table borders not drawn in HTML4+

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I got another problem, this time with tables and their borders in HTML (4.01, 5.0)

Notice: All codes are from w3schools.com

When using this code:

```
<h4>One row and three columns:</h4>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Everything is drawn correctly in the browser (FF, IE, Opera, Chrome), but when the `border="1"` is changed with `style="border: 1px;"` the borders and cell walls disappear.
I can't find the reason, but using `style` gives me the precious validation.

That's my main file sections:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>
Title of the document
</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color:teal;}
</style>
</head>
```

I hope someone here knows where's the problem is ...
Here are the results with classic `border` and `style`:

`http://www.free imagehosting.net/pyk3e << border="1"`

`http://www.free imagehosting.net/cw98o << style="border: 1px solid black;" for cells too`

Comment: The image links are now dead making the question unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need `border: 1px solid;`.  Having the pixels alone isn't enough, you have to tell the browser what to do with them.  :)

**But remember** that if you use `<table style="border: 1px solid">`, that will create a border around the *TABLE*, not the *cells within the table*.

You'll need to specify a border for the cells too.

You should probably just specify a stylesheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
  TABLE, TD {
    border: 1px solid;
  }
</style>
```

Or even, identify your table or TD blocks with an ID or a class, then use that in your stylesheet, so you don't affect other innocent bystander tables.

Comment: Ok, did that but the results are the same:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/pyk3e
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/oyeuy

Even when setting up the cells

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RepNM/ .  What result are you trying to get, anyway?  The first of the images in your question, or the second?  Or something else?

Comment: To achieve equal browser rendering results when using `border=` or `style=` so to pass the validation. Look the images from the question
Remove the tick from jsfiddle.net 'Normalise CSS' and see

Answer (score 3):

You may have to define the border, perhaps by specifying a type and color, try using:

```
style='border: 1px solid black;'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a border color too.

```
style="border:1px solid #aaa;"
```

so what you are actually setting is 
`border-size` , `border-style`, and `border-color`

[W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Comment: Using color makes the borders all black, using ridge is not drawing borders like `border="1"`, and using `style='border: 1px solid black;'` doesn't draw them too :(

Comment: You dont need both, using style is much more powerful, and it does not have to be black, you can change it to any color

Comment: I just wanna use the defaults for the table drawing, nothing more than setting the border size ...

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, you need a border color:

```
style="border:1px solid #000;"
```

Also, the style property will only apply to the table tag. If you want the cell walls to appear too, the style must be applied to the td tags.